# JasperReports - Cumulative sum in crosstab footer

Tags: java, jasper-reports, crosstab, cumulative-sum, dynamic-jasper

Is it possible to get cumulative sum in **crosstab** element in JasperReports (last row in picture beneath)? I "just" need some variable to hold value of previous column total.

[image]

Instead of last row, i tried to add (after crosstab element) 1 static text with value "Cumulative" and after that horizontal list with cumulative values (i have cumulative values already calculated in my XML datasource). It is OK solution if number of columns is let's say less then 5,6,7 **and** if crosstab should stay aligned to the left (i align it programmaticaly to middle with Java API before exporting). Aligment breaks down if elements are centered horizontaly or if table splits in multiple parts because of number of columns.

I also tried to get "measure of total measure" or something similar using measures, parameters and variables but can't get it to work.

DynamicJasper also don't seem to have solution to this (i tested it just today so sorry if i missed something in its API).

If you have any solution using whether Jaspersoft Studio, JasperReport API or DynamicJasper please help. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

OK, so since i create my own XML datasource, i decided to make workaround.

Originaly XML file structure was like:

```
<rootElement>
    <company>
        <name>Company A</name>
        <percentage>0.0509</percentage>
        <value>10000</value>
    </company>
    <company>
        <name>Company B</name>
        <percentage>0.0433</percentage>
        <value>10000</value>
    </company>
    <!-- and the rest goes here -->
</rootElement>
```

Row **Total** was calculated with measure with calculation type **Sum**, and value expression was on field **value**.

To get row **Cumulative** i add one more child element to each `<company>` tag, so XML structure is:

```
<rootElement>
    <company>
        <name>Company A</name>
        <percentage>0.0509</percentage>
        <value>10000</value>
        <cumulativePerPercentage>38000</cumulativePerPercentage>
    </company>
    <company>
        <name>Company B</name>
        <percentage>0.0433</percentage>
        <value>10000</value>
        <cumulativePerPercentage>66000</cumulativePerPercentage>
    </company>
    <!-- and the rest goes here -->
</rootElement>
```

For **Cumulative** row, i create new measure on field **cumulativePerPercentage**, with calculation type **Average**.